# How do I detect the selected object in a JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, object, selection, jcombobox

I have made a JComboBox and populated it with the result of toString of an object type which I created myself.

I want to be able to call upon the selected object from the JComboBox and then use a method from its class. However, even though my JComboBox only contains one object type (The one I made), Java doesn't know this and therefore I can;t use something like...

```
MyObject selectedObject = MyComboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

as Java cannot accept that only a "MyObject" will ever be selected.

How am I supposed to get the user to select an object of my own?

Comment: Did you populate it with the `toString` values or your actual objects?

Comment: Java 7 now allows you to supply generics to both the JList and ListModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need cast it, like

MyObject selectedObject = (MyObject) MyComboBox.getSelectedItem();

Comment: I wanted to earlier but I couldn't as it wanted me to wait 10 minutes. Will do now though :)